# Reveal hidden objects in a view in Storyboard

Tags: objective-c, xcode, storyboard

I have a problem - I hid some buttons that I am using in the code(hide/reveal), but I need to add some features to my view and I am unable to locate them. I mean, sure I can click them and will probably find them, but is there a way how to turn on "show hidden views" in XCode(4.4), or anything like that?

Comment: By 'hidden' you mean that you've checked the 'hidden' checkbox  in the view inspector?

Comment: Yes, I could unclick hidden, but there are many of them...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok there are two ways to do this:

1. **The sane (safe) way** (I know you wont like it but I have to mention it)

   Just select all your views and uncheck the **hidden** checkbox in the view inspector
2. **The adventurous way** (Be careful !)

   If you really have a lot of views hidden and you like to unhide **all** of them you can just open your Storyboard into a text editor and do a mass replace of `hidden="YES"` with `hidden="NO"` (you can see that it's just an XML with your view graph actually)

Comment: Gosh, didn't think of that...Apple is spoiling developers, we tend to get used to storyboards and forget about XMLs:)